# MPI Segmentation fault on MPI_Finalize() / using MPI_Type_vector

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to use MPI_Type_vector to swap data in the columns of two matrices.

Here's my code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Create the matrix we want to swap from
    int data[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) data[i] = rank;

    // set up a datatype to pull a column from the matrix.
    MPI_Datatype COLUMN;
    MPI_Type_vector(10, 1, 10, MPI_INT, &COLUMN);
    MPI_Type_commit(&COLUMN);
    
    // Allocate space for requests and figure out the destination.
    MPI_Request reqs[2];
    int dest = rank == 0 ? 1 : 0;

    // If I remove these 2 lines, I don't crash
    MPI_Send_init(&data[0], 10, COLUMN, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
    MPI_Recv_init(&data[0], 10, COLUMN, dest, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);

    // Start the requests.
    MPI_Startall(2, reqs);
    
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

When I cout everything in the first 10 elements of data for both processes (I'm running with 2 processes), It just says their process number, indicating that the swap did not work.  I also get a Segmentation fault on MPI_Finalize();

What am I doing wrong with MPI_Type_vector? Why doesn't it work? and then, why do I get a segmentation fault?

Thanks.

EDIT: In response to @Victor Eijkhout

```cpp
    MPI_Startall(2, reqs);
    
    MPI_Waitall(2, reqs, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    
    MPI_Request_free(&reqs[0]);
    MPI_Request_free(&reqs[1]);

    MPI_Type_free(&COLUMN);
```

Making these changes, I still get the same error on Finalization.

The type vector is working now, however.

Comment: If you plan to use persistent communications, you cannot use overlapping buffers (same buffer and same datatype here). `MPI_Sendrecv_replace()` can do that for you, but I am not sure there is a persistent subroutine for that in the MPI standard yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting a bunch of finalizations. For cleanliness you should `MPI_Type_free` but that is of minor importance. Bigger is that `MPI_Startall` needs to be balanced with `MPI_Waitall`, and then `MPI_Request_free` for those requests. You are basically leaving your program in a very undefined state by skipping the Wait call.

Next, your `COLUMN` type has 10 times a stride of 10, so it is 91 elements long: 9 times an element plus gap, but no gap after the 10th block. And then you're sending 10 of those, meaning that you pick your data from 900-some elements of array. You were hoping that your 10 columns would start at consecutive locations, right? This is possible: you need to use `MPI_Type_create_resized` to artificially set the "extent" of the type to `sizeof(int)`.

```
MPI_Datatype newcolumn;
MPI_Type_create_resized(COLUMN,0,sizeof(int),&newcolumn);
MPI_Type_commit(&newcolumn);
MPI_Send( array, 10,newcolumn, ...... )
```

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for responding. I've made your changes,
but I still get an error. I've edited the post to show the changes.

Comment: Your type handling needs a non-obvious trick. Added to my answer.

Comment: Ohhhh, 10x10 COLUMNs, not individual indexes. Probably should have picked up on that.  Thanks, Victor!

Comment: If the intent is to send/recv the full matrix, then better send it by row than by columns!